# Meteor require don't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, require

I try to use eventEmitter in my meteor project.

And when I write :

```
Meteor.require('events');
```

Nothing happen...

No error and my code after this line doesn't work...

Have you an idea ? thanks you

EDIT

I'm trying to do this :

```
Deps.autorun(function () {
Meteor.emit('even', Session.get('testok'));
});


var events = Npm.require('events'),


test = new events.EventEmitter;

test.on('even', function (chaine) {
console.log('lol');
console.log(chaine);
});
```

I try to make an emit when the Session.get('testok') change.

Comment: I don't think there is such thing as `Meter.require`. Maybe, you were thinking about `Npm.require`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eventEmitter` is part of Meteor core, and shouldn't be referenced by your app. Furthermore, there is no `Meteor.require`.

If you post some of your code and explain what you're trying to accomplish, perhaps the community can be of help.

Comment: Meteor is reactive. You shouldn't need to write any code to handle the "event" of a Session variable changing. Merely the fact of it changing should cause all templates and other functions that reference it to re-run. See http://docs.meteor.com/#reactivity